# WinSCP: Unknown command 'winscp.com'

Tags: ftp, winscp

I am trying to use WinSCP to automate some basic FTP tasks so I have downloaded and setup the latest WinSCP 5.7.7 however I keep getting the following error when trying to execute the .bat with the script I have created. I am running Windows 10 Pro 1511

Error I get from running the .bat file.

> Unknown command 'winscp.com'.

---

ftp.bat

```
winscp.com /script="C:\AutoRun\ftp-script.txt" 

pause
```

---

ftp-script.txt

```
winscp.com /log=ftp.log /command ^ 
    "open ftp://user:pass@url.com/" ^ 
    "put -latest C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Test\* / 
    "exit"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run `winscp.com` from `winscp.com`. WinSCP obviously does not recognize the `winscp.com` as its command.

---

Your `ftp-script.txt` is not a [WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#using_scripting), it's actually a Windows batch file.

- Delete your `ftp.bat`.
- Rename the `ftp-script.txt` to `ftp.bat`.
- Append `pause` to its end.
- And run it.

---

Then you will hit second issue, that you are missing a double-quote and a caret after the `put -latest C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Test\* /`:

```
winscp.com /log=ftp.log /command ^ 
    "open ftp://user:pass@url.com/" ^ 
    "put -latest C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Test\* /" ^
    "exit"
```

---

Then you will hit third issue, that the [`-latest` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#latest) is supported by the WinSCP 5.8.x only, not by 5.7.7 (the latest 5.8.3 in release candidate).

---

See also WinSCP FAQ [Why are some WinSCP scripting commands specified in a batch file not executed/failing?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file)